# Does Unicode have a special marker character?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, special-characters

My father created in mid 90's an encoding for his engineering purposes for his company's computers. It was close to ISO 8859-2 (Latin 2), but with some differences.

For example there was added a special "MARKER CHARACTER". This character wasn't determined to be a literal, but also it wasn't a control character.

The purpose of this character was to be inserted by machine when needed to split text into parts. See the following Python parser script:

```py
re.sub(r'\{\{', r'~{{', text)
re.sub(r'\[\[', r'~[[', text)
re.sub(r'\]\]', r']]~', text)
re.sub(r'\}\}', r'}}~', text)
parts = text.strip('~').split('~')
inCurly = [False]
inSharp = [False]
whereAmI = ['']

for part in parts:
    if part[:2] == '{{':
        inCurly.append(True)
        whereAmI.append('Curly')
    elif part[:2] == '[[':
        inSharp.append(True)
        whereAmI.append('Sharp')

if whereAmI[-1] == 'Sharp' and not inCurly[-1]:
    # some advanced magic on current part,
    # if it is directly surrounded by sharp brackets,
    # but these sharp brackets are not in curly brackets anyhow
    # (not: "{{ (( [[ some text ]] )) }}")

# detecting closing brackets and popping inSharp, inCurly, whereAmI
# joining parts back to text
```

This is an easy parser for advanced purposes, you can detect more parenthesis or quotation marks as you want. But this have one huge fault. It break things when a `~` is in text.

For this purpose and similar purposes like this (but in C lang I think) he added to his encoding/character set that marker character.

For years I use for this purpose three german "sharp s": `ßßß`, because it is almost impossible to see three of them in a row. But this is not an ideal solution.

Yesterday my father told me this story and I immediatelly thought: is there some equivalent in an Unicode family? Unicode is a modern developing standard spreaded all over the world in past decade drastically. There should be a special character only for this particular purpose, or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything called that specifically, but you might find *zero-width space* or *information separator*, among others, suitable for the purpose. You can arbitrarily select any character as your marker, and use an escape character if it occurs within the string.

In the control pictures block, there is a symbol for the *group separator*.

Comment: Well, as I said, I use three letters sharp s

Comment: Note that, if you can insert separator or marker characters, you can also insert an escape character in front of ß (or any other character). Or, if you want something guaranteed to be unused, there's U+FFFF. U+FFF9, the *interlinear annotation anchor*, is also somewhat similar.